# Upload Multiple Images Android Java

Tags: java, android

I trying to upload multiple images from gallery.However if I choose just one its work. I use the library volley plus SimpleMultiPartRequest smr bla bla bla

```
 ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).path + (i < l-1 ? "," : ""));
        } String imagepath = stringBuffer.toString()
          smr.addFile("file[]", imagePath);
```

Comment: And if you choose five?

Comment: @greenapps yes I chose

Comment: And then.. What happens?

Comment: @greenapps I said that i need to upload a few images to server using the file[]

Comment: Yes i know. You dont have to tell me again. Why dont you understand what im asking? If you add one then one is uploaded. Ok. If you add five then how many are uploaded? Saying that it does not work tells us nothing!